# Automatically continue Markdown list in Geany?

Tags: markdown, geany

- I write a lot of lists.
- Like this one.
- Very long lists, in fact.
- But I hate having to manually type the `*` on each new line.
- Is there any way to get Geany to automatically produce the `*` when I break a line that's already in a list?